# Как в массиве удалить последние элементы

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, суть следующая: функция `deleteEvenElements` удаляет чётные элементы в массиве, но после удаления при выводе массива происходит повтор чисел. Например  [1,2,4,4,5] после удаления чётных чисел должно быть [1,5] ,а получается  [1,5,4,4,5] . 
Как сделать,что бы остались элементы, которые не были удалены и ничего более?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
void generateArray(int *arr, int n);
void showArray(int *arr, int n);
int searchMin(int *arr, int n);
int searchMax(int *arr, int n);
void echangeMinMax(int *arr, int index_of_min, int index_of_max);
void sortUpArray(int *arr, int n);
void deleteEvenElements(int *arr, int &n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int *arr = new int[n];
    generateArray(arr, n);

    cout << "isxodni masiv :" << endl;
    showArray(arr, n); // Вывод массива на экран.

    int index_of_min = searchMin(arr, n);//  индекс минимального значения
    cout << "Min = " << arr[index_of_min] << endl;

    int index_of_max = searchMax(arr, n);
    cout << "Max= " << arr[index_of_max] << endl; // индекс максимального значения.

    echangeMinMax(arr, index_of_min, index_of_max); //меняем макс и мин местами
    cout << "Min i max obmen : " << endl;
    showArray(arr, n); //Вывод массива на экран.

    cout << "Sortirovka na vozrastanie : " << endl;
    sortUpArray(arr,n);// Соритровка на возрастание.
    showArray(arr, n); // Вывод массива на экран.

    cout << "Udalenie chetnix elmentof : " << endl;
    deleteEvenElements(arr, n);
    showArray(arr, n); // Вывод массива на экран.

    delete[] arr;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

void generateArray(int *arr, int n)
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        arr[i] = rand() % (b - a + 1) + a;
}
void showArray(int *arr, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int searchMin(int *arr, int n)
{
    int index_of_min = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]<arr[index_of_min])
        {
            index_of_min = i;

        }
    }

    return index_of_min;
}

int searchMax(int *arr, int n)
{
    int index_of_max = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>arr[index_of_max])
        {
            index_of_max = i;

        }
    }

    return index_of_max;
}
void echangeMinMax(int *arr, int index_of_min, int index_of_max)
{
    swap(arr[index_of_min], arr[index_of_max]);
}

void sortUpArray(int *arr, int n)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j<n; j++)
        {

            if (arr[i]>arr[j])
            {
                swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
            }

        }
    }
}

void deleteEvenElements(int *arr, int &n)// чётные элементы
{
    int newsize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) 
    if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) arr[newsize++] = arr[i];
    for (int i = 0; i<newsize; i++) ;

}
```

Comment: [mcve] бы... А вообще  вы переменную с размером массива (newsize) потеряли и не передали для вывода. (допишите `n = newsize`)  `for (int i = 0; i<newsize; i++) ;` зачем эта строка кстати?)

Comment: мой любимый вопрос - std::vector запретили?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ заставить код работать

```
void deleteEvenElements(int *arr, int &n)// чётные элементы
{
    int newsize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) 
    if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) arr[newsize++] = arr[i];
    n = newsize;
}
```

То есть, по факту, ничего не удаляем. А просто возвращаем исправленный размер.

Но нужно помнить, что в с++ для массива, созданного через new нельзя изменить размер. Только создать новый и скопировать туда элементы. Но если писать все таки на си (а Ваш код написан формально на чистом си), то там есть realloc, которая собственно и решает задачу. В нормальном с++ принято использовать std::vector.